Numerical Integration via NIntegrate of an oscillatory function is too slow and gives errors
I would like to numerically integrate the following function for different values of $x$: $f(x) = -\frac{G^2}{8\sqrt{2}\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp'\frac{W_{p}W_{p'}W_{p+p'}}{E_{p} E_{p'}E_{p+p'}} f_{\text{tot}}(p,p')\cos(px)$, where $\epsilon_p =\sqrt{p^2 + \frac{p^4}{4}}, W_p = \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2* \epsilon_p}}, E_p = \epsilon_p - vp$, $ f_{\text{tot}}(p,p') = \left[\left(\frac{\epsilon_{p} \epsilon_{p'}}{pp'}+\frac{3\epsilon_{p} \epsilon_{p + p'}}{p(p+p')} + \frac{\epsilon_{p'} \epsilon_{p+p'}}{p'(p+p')}\right) + \frac{3}{4}\left(pp' - p \left(p + p'\right) - p' \left(p + p'\right)\right)\right] \frac{\left|pp'\left(p + p'\right) \right|}{\sqrt{\epsilon_{p} \epsilon_{p'} \epsilon_{p +p'}}}$, and $G$ and $v$ are $p$-independent constants. I have written the following mathematica code for producing a table of the format {x, f(x)} for $x \in [-10,10]$:
Clear["Global`*"];
G = 0.1;
c2 = G^2/(8*Sqrt[2]*Pi^2);
v0 = 0.1;
E1[p_] := Sqrt[p^2 + p^4/4.0];
E2[p_] := E1[p] - v0*p;
W[p_] := Sqrt[p^2/(2*E1[p])];
functot[k_, 
   k1_] := (((E1[k]*E1[k1])/(k*k1) + 
       3.0*(E1[k]*E1[k + k1])/(k*(k + k1)) + (E1[k1]*E1[k + k1])/(
       k1*(k + k1))) + 3/4*(k*k1 - k*(k + k1) - k1*(k + k1)))*
   Abs[k*k1*(k + k1)]/Sqrt[E1[k]*E1[k1]*E1[k + k1]];
T3 = Table[{x, -c2*
    NIntegrate[(W[p]*W[p1]*W[p + p1])/(E2[p]*E2[p1]*E2[p + p1])*
       Cos[p*x]*functot[p, p1], {p, -Infinity,Infinity}, {p1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      Method -> "LevinRule"]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.5}]

With this code, there are two problems:

There are the following error messages:


NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.


NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained -0.000893573 and 0.012599548568652672` for the integral and error estimates.


The code takes extremely long time to compute.

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica where the problems can be avoided? I am specifically interested in making the code faster.

If I look at the output of FullSimplify[..yourIntegrand..] then I see lots of examples like Sqrt[(p+p1)^2*(4+(p+p1)^2)] Is there any chance that with great care it might be possible to pull most or all of those squared terms outside the square roots, getting rid of most or all of the square roots? If that is possible to exactly correctly do then your problem might far simpler and thus perhaps far faster. That might involve, as a first step, introducing more Abs and those sometimes make integration slower. With more care maybe you can integrate over p>p1 or p,p1>0 and make this simple

Suggest you change all decimal constants to rational  (0.1-> 1/10 and so on).   I noticed when I Plot3D the integrand in (-5,5} at x=3 there are  abrupt changes along diagonal p2=-p and maybe along p2=0.  Then perhaps split integral into 6 parts along these borders.  Try:  Plot3D[((W[p]*W[p1]*W[p + p1])/(E2[p]*E2[p1]*E2[p + p1])*Cos[p*x]*     functot[p, p1]) /. x -> 3, {p, -5, 5}, {p1, -5, 5},   PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100] to see these.
